# Function isn't creating an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a function that uses an onclick event to show an input field. Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="createMessage()">New Message</button>

<script>

function createMessage() {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.className = "message_input"; 
    container.appendChild(input);
};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where's `container`? please post your **full** code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a complete source of your page - you don't have element called "container". In a simplest case you can add your new input field to document itself.

Replace

```
container.appendChild(input);
```

with

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(input);
```